# App where i can see my friends location

Tags: facebook, google-maps, userlocation, facebook-friends

I'm developing a google maps based app. I would like to integrate the capabilities of being able to see your friends location/s (similar to how you can see uber cars or fiend my friends). currently i have a facebook signin option. Does anyone know what sdk i need to integrate or the name of what this is called so that i can do further research.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get the location of Facebook friends, friend permissions are completely gone for privacy reasons: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

You can only get the location of an authorized User (with the `user_location` permission), see Facebook docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user

Comment: Will google+ be able to give me that capability? Facebook sign in my preferred method for user to be able to use the app. I'm also looking into Amazon AWS

Comment: i am pretty sure does not allow you to get access to the location of friends either. it would be a major privacy issue.

Comment: how does uber, find my friends and other similar apps do it?

Comment: they are most likely using a v1.0 app